# Simplifying regex in Haskell with trees

Tags: regex, haskell, tree

I have this data structure for regular expressions (RE), and so far I do not have any functions modifying REs:

```
data Regex a = Letter a | Emptyword | Concat (Regex a) (Regex a) | Emptyset | Or (Regex a) (Regex a) | Star (Regex a)
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I would like to implement a simplification algorithm for my REs. For this I thought I should first represent the RE as tree, update the tree according to some equivalences and then convert it back to a RE. My reasoning was that with trees I would have functions to find, extract and attach subtrees, update values etc.

However, I have difficulties finding a tree module giving these functionalities and being simple enough for a beginner to learn.
I found this [avl-tree package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/AvlTree-4.2/docs/Data-Tree-AVL.html) however, it seems very large.

I'd like to have alternative suggestions to my approach with trees and suggestions on easy tree modules supporting mentioned functions.
Note that I'm a beginner in Haskell and I do not understand monads yet and that I'm not interested in an implementation to simplify REs.

**Edit 1:** We know that the following two REs are equivalent, where `L b` stands for `Letter b` and `C` for `Concat`:

```
    Or                          Or
   /  \                        / \
  L b  C            =        L b  L a
      /  \                        
    L a  Emptyword
```

So given the left RE I'd like to replace the subtree with its root labeled by `C` with a node labeled by `L a`. As was pointed out my data structure is a tree structure. However, currently I do not have functions to, e.g. replace a subtree with a node, or find a subtree of a structure that I can replace.

Comment: Your `Regex` datatype is already a tree.

Comment: I assume `Emptyset` is a pattern that doesn't match anything? If so, it seems an awkward thing to put in that type, and it might be best to remove it.

Comment: "... update the tree ..." - the FP approach is to _define_ values. It would help if you gave a concrete example of a transformation or analysis that you want to perform on your regular expressions.

Comment: I'm quite sure this application wants nothing to do with AVL trees :-).

Comment: @dfeuer the `EmptySet` certainly belongs to the [RegEx definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition). Hint: the intersection of two regular is regular as well, but can be empty. Would make a nice SO question why the empty set is missing in most implementations.

Comment: @Franky, it may well be most efficient to represent it in the same sum type, but you likely *don't* want to have something like `Star EmptySet` or `Or EmptySet e`, and you can enforce that by using `data NE a = Word a | ...` and `data Regex a = EmptySet | NERegex (NE a)`.

Comment: But I guess that would represent some sort of "optimized" regex, and you may also want to be able to represent one with extra stuff... Hmmm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you already have a tree. You can simplify right away:

```
simplify :: Regex a -> Regex a
simplify (Star Emptyset)   = Emptyword
simplify (Star (Star x))   = Star (simplify x)
simplify (Concat x Emptyword) = simplify x
simplify (Concat Emptyword y) = simplify y
simplify (Or x y) | x == y = x
-- or rather simplify (Or x y) | simplify x == simplify y = simplify x
-- more sophisticated rules here
-- ...
-- otherwise just push down
simplify (Or x y) = simplify (Or (simplify x) (simplify y)
-- ...
simplify x@(Letter _) = x
```

This is just superficial, e.g. the first rule should be `simplify (Star x) | simplify x == Emptyset = emptyword`.

### AVL Trees

AVL trees are for balance, not really applicable here. The only place where balance make sense is for the associative operations

```
Or (x (Or y z) == Or (Or x y) y
```

I suggest to use lists for those operations

```
data Regex' a = Letter' a | Concat' [Regex a]  | Or [Regex a] | Star (Regex a)
deriving (Show, Eq)
```

(No `Emptyword'` because it is `Concat' []`; same with `Emptyset'` and `Or`.)
Converting between `Regex` and `Regex'` is the usual exercise for the reader.

### General Hardness

Note that Regex equivalence is not easy:

```
(a|b)* = (a*b)*a*
```

Optimizing `Or "(a|b)*" "(a*b)*a*"` is hard...

Comment: Seems much better than mine. Thanks!